# passing DOMDocument and DOMElement to PHP function

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I wrote two functions for finding elements by className in PHP DOMDOcument

```
function byClass(DOMDocument $a,$b,$c){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName($b) as $e){
        if($e->getAttribute('class')==$c){$r[]=$e;}
    }
return $r;
}

function byClass2(DOMElement $a,$b,$c){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName($b) as $e){
        if($e->getAttribute('class')==$c){$r[]=$e;}
    }
return $r;
}
```

Is it possible to merge these two functions into one by auto-detecting if the first argument is `DOMDocument` or `DOMElement`?

Comment: Why do you need to detect? The code is the same in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DOMDocument` and `DOMElement` are both subclasses of `DOMNode`, so use that type to encompass both.

```
function byClass(DOMNode $a,$b,$c){
    foreach($a->getElementsByTagName($b) as $e){
        if($e->getAttribute('class')==$c){$r[]=$e;}
    }
    return $r;
}
```